# SQL order by match to specific row

Tags: mysql, count, match

I have a example table below.  I am trying to create a SQL query that gets all user_ids besides user_id of the current user and then orders by number of matches to the row with the current user_id

For example, if the user has a user_id of '1', I want to get all of the user_ids corresponding with the rows of id 2-8, and then order the user_ids from most matches to the row of the current user to least matches with the row of the current user

Let's say var current_user = 1

Something like this:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM assets
WHERE user_id <> `current_user` and
ORDER BY most matches to `current_user`"
```

The output should get 7,8,3,9,2

```
I would appreciate anyone's input on how I can effectively achieve this.

Table assets
+----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
|    id    | user_id |  cars | houses | boats | 
+----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
|    1     |    1    |   3   |   2    |   3   |
|    2     |    8    |   3   |   2    |   5   |
|    3     |    3    |   3   |   2    |   2   |
|    4     |    2    |   5   |   1    |   5   |
|    5     |    9    |   5   |   7    |   3   |
|    8     |    7    |   3   |   2    |   3   |
+----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just do this:

```
select a.*
from assets a cross join
     assets a1
where a1.user_id = 1 and a.user_id <> a1.user_id
order by ( (a.cars = a1.cars) + (a.houses = a1.houses) + (a.boats = a1.boats) ) desc;
```

In MySQL, a boolean expression is treated as an integer in a numeric context, with 1 for true and 0 for false.

If you want to be fancier, you could order by the total difference:

```
order by ( abs(a.cars - a1.cars) + abs(a.houses - a1.houses) + abs(a.boats - a1.boats) );
```

This is called Manhattan distance, and you would be implementing a version of a nearest neighbor model.